# Karate : Visual Studio Code: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.intuit.karate.cli.Main

Tags: karate

Error when I run the file.

An exception occured while executing the Java class. Using visual studio code for api tets

com.intuit.karate.cli.Main ->

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.intuit.karate.cli.Main
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass (URLClassLoader.java:471)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:588)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:521)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run (ExecJavaMojo.java:270)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:834)
```

Running karate feature file in visual studio code.

This is how my pom.xml file looks

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

      <groupId>com.allegion.engage</groupId>
      <artifactId>Engage</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1</version>

      <name>Engage</name>
      <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
      <url>http://www.example.com</url>

      <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
      </properties>

      <dependencies>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
          <artifactId>karate-apache</artifactId>
          <version>0.9.4</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
          <artifactId>karate-junit4</artifactId>
          <version>0.9.4</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <version>4.8</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
          <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

      </dependencies>

      <build>
        <testResources>
          <testResource>
            <directory>src/test/java</directory>
            <excludes>
              <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
          </testResource>
        </testResources>
        <pluginManagement>
          <!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
          <plugins>
            <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
            <plugin>
              <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>3.1.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
            <plugin>
              <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>3.0.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
              <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>3.8.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
              <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.22.1</version>
              <configuration>
                <skipTests>true</skipTests>
              </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
              <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>3.0.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
              <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.5.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
              <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.8.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
            <plugin>
              <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>3.7.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
              <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>3.0.0</version>
            </plugin>
          </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
      </build>
    </project>

package com.allegion.engage.Login;

    import com.intuit.karate.KarateOptions;

    @KarateOptions(features = "classpath:Login/Login.feature")
    public class LoginRunner{

    }


    Feature: Login and get the token

      Scenario: Login and get the token

        Given url loginUrl
        And request  {username: 'someusername', password: 'test' }
        When method POST
        Then status 200
        And def authToken = response
        Then print authToken
```

Kindly helo if I have missed any run configurations. I am using vscode in mac.

Comment: @PeterThomas I apologize for not marking the answer for previous question as accepted. I did now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`com.intuit.karate.cli.Main` is only in 0.9.5 onwards, so can you point your dependencies to karate version 0.9.5.RC3

This is mentioned in the docs BTW: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kirkslota.karate-runner